# In serialport data received event It says The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port, ioexception

i am integrating VS and Arduino IDE together for my Iot project. I have to read data and display it in VS IDE..which i am able to. only the first 3 values are been read not the other 3, inside the serial data received event. Previously i was able to read data but not display it.the error that i got was cross threading, which i rectified using delegate. Now i am not able to read.
Exception: System.IO.IOException: 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

```
VS Code

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox("dfghjk");

            moist = serialPort1.ReadLine();  //can read
            temper = serialPort1.ReadLine(); //can read
            humid = serialPort1.ReadLine();  //can read

            SetTextMo(moist);   //can set
            SetTextTe(temper);//can set
            SetTextHu(humid);//can set

            resMois = serialPort1.ReadLine();  //cannot read (exception mentioned above occurs)
            resTemp = serialPort1.ReadLine();  //cannot read (exception mentioned above occurs)
            resHumi = serialPort1.ReadLine();  //cannot read (exception mentioned above occurs)


            SetTextResM(resMois); //can set
            SetTextResT(resTemp);//can set
            SetTextResH(resHumi);   //can set
        }
```

```
Arduino Code

void loop() 
{    
    if(a == 0)
    {
      if(Serial.available() > 0) 
        {
            mySt = Serial.readString();
            i = mySt.toInt();
            if (i==1) 
            {
                checkCurrentValue();//works perfect
                suitablePlant();//works perfect
                a++;
            }  
            else if(i==2)
            {
                crop = Serial.readString();
                checkCurrentValue();//values of the data i can read belong too this function
                checkParameters();//values of data belonging to this function i am unable to read 
                a++;
            } 
            else{}
        }
   }                    
}
```

Comment: Just guessing but, you are probably sending checkCurrentValue() and checkParameters() data in different packets and thus the event is probably triggered twice. Check in your event handler if `e.EventType == SerialData.Eof` and read no more if it is. Your event handler will probably be triggered when the next packet arrives

Comment: Do you have a main method?